# spring cloud config client load plain text from server

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

As the title, I wonder if there is some way to get rendered plain text from config server.

I found a way from [How Spring Cloud Config Server PUSH plain text files to Config Client Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608323/how-spring-cloud-config-server-push-plain-text-files-to-config-client-applicatio).

`restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/application/default/master/testing-dev.json",String.class);`

But this way, require a full url-path to the plain text.

Is there some awesome way just like getting property from `Environment`?

For example, `configEnv` is the client-side object.
`configEnv.getResource("testing-dev.json")`
can get a rendered plain text config from config server.

Comment: Not that I am aware of